# How can I prevent OS X Lion from automatically re-opening previous documents?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

On Snow Leopard when you closed Preview.app and open another document with it, the previous documents did not reopen. On Lion, however, it seems that Preview is always reopening things that I thought I closed. How can I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use a utility called [RestoreMeNot](http://www.stealthycactus.com/restoremenot/) for disabling window restoration for individual applications.

[image]

It's a System Preference Pane that allows you to exclude apps from Mac OS X 10.7 Lion's Application Resume feature.

Comment: It's just a UI to `defaults write NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows`, but nevertheless quite useful.

Answer (score 4):

Resume can be disabled from System Preferences:

[image]

---

You can also override that setting for individual apps with something like:

```
defaults write com.apple.Preview NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false
```

---

Most apps now have an action called *Quit and Close All Windows* or *Quit and Keep Windows* under <kbd>⌥⌘Q</kbd> depending on the default set in System Preferences.

---

You can also prevent windows from being reopened by holding shift while opening an application. (It works when the application is opened from the Dock, Launchpad, or Finder, but not when using the Spotlight menu or some third party apps or scripts). And it doesn't work the other way around when Resume is disabled either.

Comment: Have you figured out how to enable it again from `defaults`? It ignored the value for me (only checks if set), and `defaults delete` does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Or, you can use cmd+option+q to quit the Preview.app.  The next time opening the Preview.app, won't restore the window.  The same method can be used for other application (e.g, Safari)

Answer (score 2):

You can uncheck the "Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps" checkbox in System Preference -> General.

It will not reopen things any more.

But after this setting, the preview no longer keep the last position of reading. Seems no perfect way to fix this.